# Laravel – Session Store not set when using request() in controller __constructor

Tags: laravel

I have a cart that I use on almost every page of an application.

**Cart.php**

```
Cart{
  public $items;
  public function __constructor(){
    if(request()->session()->has('cart')){
      $this->items = request()->session()->get('cart')->items;
    }
  }
}
```

As I use this on every route, I thought I'd try to add it to the base controller:

**Controller.php**

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
  use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
  public function __construct(Request $request){
      $this->cart = new Cart();
  }
}
```

This leads to the error:

> Session store not set on request.

Which I think I understand... I guess the controllers are instantiated before the session has been booted. But the routes I'm using are all on the `web` middleware.

How can I either just make the above work, or make sure the session is ready to be accessed, and share my shopping cart class across the whole application?

Comment: You could create a private function with that logic and call it in your other controller functions

Comment: This has been asked many times. Joseph Silber documented some nice [alternatives](https://josephsilber.com/posts/2017/01/23/getting-current-user-in-laravel-controller-constructor).

Comment: @Mozammil ahhh thanks that link looks really promising

Answer (score 0):

There is some data that is no available at execution of the constructor of the controllers.

There are many options to solve this but I would recommend you extend the `BaseController` and create a method that loads the data from your cart into your items variable.
With this you can extend your cart related controllers from your extended controller.

Other option could be use trait to store the possible operations to load or handler your cart items and add it where you need.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the help of the link from @Mozammil by using the inline middleware option, so my new Controller that I extended from looked like this:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{

  use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
  public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
      $this->cart = new Cart();
      return $next($request);
    });
  }

}
```

Now I can access the cart in any controller of my application.